# replace the data in datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the html table with 5 column as date which I want to convert the date format if the data is not empty.I'm using moment.js for date format.

Now date format is converted perfectly but empty column displays invalid date.So I want to check if the cell is not empty I have tried as
[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e19ac4u0/)

```js
//
// Updates "Select all" control in a data table
//
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table){
   var $table             = table.table().node();
   var $chkbox_all        = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
   var $chkbox_checked    = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
   var chkbox_select_all  = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

   // If none of the checkboxes are checked
   if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If all of the checkboxes are checked
   } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If some of the checkboxes are checked
   } else {
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
      }
   }
}

$(document).ready(function (){
   // Array holding selected row IDs
   var rows_selected = [];
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      //'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
      'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'width':'1%',
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox">';
         }
        
      },{
      'targets': 5,
      render:function (data, type, row) {if(data!=null) return moment(data).format('YYYY-MMM-DD');}
      }],
      pageLength: 5,
      'order': [1, 'asc'],
      'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
         // Get row ID
         var rowId = data[0];

         // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
         if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
            $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(row).addClass('selected');
         }
      }
   });

 

  
    
   // Handle form submission event 
   
});
```

```css
table.dataTable.select tbody tr,
table.dataTable thead th:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<h3><a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">jQuery DataTables – Row selection using checkboxes</a></h3>
<a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
<hr><br>
    
<form id="frm-example" action="/path/to/your/script" method="POST">
    
<table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Airi Satou</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/11/28</td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Airi </td>
   <td>typist</td>
   <td>chennai</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/11/28</td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>priya</td>
   <td>Acntant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$72,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/10/28</td>
   <td>$75,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$2,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<hr>


</form>
```

Comment: Your question is a code dump with 4 sentences that barely explain your question. Please add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only checking the data is null. you should check data is empty also.

change the condition to `return data ? moment(data).format('YYYY-MMM-DD') : "";`

```js
//
// Updates "Select all" control in a data table
//
function updateDataTableSelectAllCtrl(table){
   var $table             = table.table().node();
   var $chkbox_all        = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]', $table);
   var $chkbox_checked    = $('tbody input[type="checkbox"]:checked', $table);
   var chkbox_select_all  = $('thead input[name="select_all"]', $table).get(0);

   // If none of the checkboxes are checked
   if($chkbox_checked.length === 0){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = false;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If all of the checkboxes are checked
   } else if ($chkbox_checked.length === $chkbox_all.length){
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = false;
      }

   // If some of the checkboxes are checked
   } else {
      chkbox_select_all.checked = true;
      if('indeterminate' in chkbox_select_all){
         chkbox_select_all.indeterminate = true;
      }
   }
}

$(document).ready(function (){
   // Array holding selected row IDs
   var rows_selected = [];
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      //'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
      'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable':false,
         'orderable':false,
         'width':'1%',
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
             return '<input type="checkbox">';
         }
        
      },{
      'targets': 5,
      render:function (data, type, row) {return data ? moment(data).format('YYYY-MMM-DD') : ""}
      }],
      pageLength: 5,
      'order': [1, 'asc'],
      'rowCallback': function(row, data, dataIndex){
         // Get row ID
         var rowId = data[0];

         // If row ID is in the list of selected row IDs
         if($.inArray(rowId, rows_selected) !== -1){
            $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            $(row).addClass('selected');
         }
      }
   });

 

  
    
   // Handle form submission event 
   
});
```

```css
table.dataTable.select tbody tr,
table.dataTable thead th:first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<h3><a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">jQuery DataTables – Row selection using checkboxes</a></h3>
<a href="http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
<hr><br>
    
<form id="frm-example" action="/path/to/your/script" method="POST">
    
<table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><input name="select_all" value="1" type="checkbox"></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Airi Satou</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/11/28</td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>Airi </td>
   <td>typist</td>
   <td>chennai</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/11/28</td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>priya</td>
   <td>Acntant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$72,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td>2008/10/28</td>
   <td>$75,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$2,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>pri</td>
   <td>Accountant</td>
   <td>Tokyo</td>
   <td>5407</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>$162,700</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<hr>


</form>
```